# Eclipse - Create a new template to add "static" word

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I'm using Eclispe IDE and i would to create to add a template that add automatically the static word at the beginning of each lines I selected . How to make that ?

```
// from
int a = 0;
String b = "hello";
float c = 0.3f;

// to 
static int a = 0;
static String b = "hello";
static float c = 0.3f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a template would work.  Try using block selection mode.  The icon looks like the second one from the left in this image.  You can also use the key binding `Alt+Shift+A`

[image: Tool bar snap shot]

Once in block mode, just position the cursor in front of your first line and continue to draw a single line down until you need to stop.  Then start typing. It will insert whatever you type in front of all the lines.  You can do a lot more with this too.

Another alternative would be to use a regular expression with find/replace on a selection.